# Use _wfopen in C code without writing BOM

Tags: c, utf-8, byte-order-mark

Is it possible to not write out the BOM at the beginning of the file? as I want to later run the file in dos and it doesn't like that.

e.g.script.bat

```
 >ï»¿
 'ï»¿' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
 >chcp 65001
 Active code page: 65001
 >mkdir c:\move
```

open code:-

```
    FILE *out;
    if((out = _wfopen(L"script.bat", L"wt+,ccs=UTF-8"))==NULL)
```

Answer (score 3):

rewind(out);  at the start did the trick.